# PostgreSQL - Can I get the inverse of distinct rows?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table of contacts. Each contact has an associating website. Each website can have multiple contacts.

I ran a query to get one contact with `Select distinct on (website)`. This works fine.

But I want to do something the the rest of the data not selected but `Select distinct on (website)`. Is there an inverse command where I can find all records from websites that have NOT been processed?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `except`. Here is an illustration. `order by` is for clarity.

```sql
create temporary table the_table (i integer, tx text);
insert into the_table values
(1, 'one'),
(1, 'one more one'),
(1, 'yet another one'),
(2, 'two'),
(2, 'one more two'),
(2, 'yet another two'),
(3, 'three'),
(3, 'three alternative');

select * from the_table
EXCEPT
select distinct on (i) * from the_table
order by i;
```

| i | tx |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | one more one |
| 1 | yet another one |
| 2 | yet another two |
| 2 | one more two |
| 3 | three alternative |